# Strange I'm getting exception but the scripts in the exception message are not exist on my pc. What should I do?

Tags: unity

I'm using unity version : 2019.2.5f1 personal

I searched on my hard disks the entire pc and none of the scripts in the exception message are exist. And the exception is happens only sometimes. When I stop the game in the editor by pressing the play button the exception is show sometimes and sometimes not.  I tried to close and open over agai the unity editor and the project. Still strange.

> MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'ReflectionProbe' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
>   Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.
>   UnityEditor.ReflectionProbeEditor.OnPreSceneGUICallback (UnityEditor.SceneView sceneView) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Inspector/ReflectionProbeEditor.cs:651)
>   UnityEditor.SceneView.CallOnPreSceneGUI () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/SceneView/SceneView.cs:3359)
>   UnityEditor.SceneView.DoOnPreSceneGUICallbacks (UnityEngine.Rect cameraRect) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/SceneView/SceneView.cs:1935)
>   UnityEditor.SceneView.OnGUI () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/SceneView/SceneView.cs:2320)
>   System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) (at <599589bf4ce248909b8a14cbe4a2034e>:0)
>   Rethrow as TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>   UnityEngine.UIElements.UIR.RenderChain.Render (UnityEngine.Rect topRect, UnityEngine.Matrix4x4 projection) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/UIElements/Renderer/UIRChainBuilder.cs:238)
>   UnityEngine.UIElements.UIRRepaintUpdater.DrawChain (UnityEngine.Rect topRect, UnityEngine.Matrix4x4 projection) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/UIElements/Renderer/UIRRepaintUpdater.cs:66)
>   UnityEngine.UIElements.UIRRepaintUpdater.Update () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/UIElements/Renderer/UIRRepaintUpdater.cs:54)
>   UnityEngine.UIElements.VisualTreeUpdater.UpdateVisualTree () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/UIElements/VisualTreeUpdater.cs:72)
>   UnityEngine.UIElements.Panel.Repaint (UnityEngine.Event e) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/UIElements/Panel.cs:637)
>   UnityEngine.UIElements.UIElementsUtility.DoDispatch (UnityEngine.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel panel) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/UIElements/UIElementsUtility.cs:240)
>   UnityEngine.UIElements.UIElementsUtility.ProcessEvent (System.Int32 instanceID, System.IntPtr nativeEventPtr) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/UIElements/UIElementsUtility.cs:78)
>   UnityEngine.GUIUtility.ProcessEvent (System.Int32 instanceID, System.IntPtr nativeEventPtr) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:179)

Comment: This usually means the script is part of the Unity internals, or a package, rather than an asset in your project's assets folder.

Comment: @DMGregory I see, And what can I do about it to fix it ? I mean where to start from to find the problem ? I have many packages in the Assets.

Comment: Looking at that error, I don't think this is something you can 'fix' yourself. The error points to [this file at line 651](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Editor/Mono/Inspector/ReflectionProbeEditor.cs). Which is the inspector of a ReflectionProbe. So I guess this is a bug you encountered. My guess is that this only happens when you have a (certain?) ReflectionProbe selected when you go out of playmode. It is probably safe to ignore this error, although you could perhaps report is as a bug.